Advice on how to speed up jax compilation times?
I want to implement the Legendre approximation of Dahlke&Pacheco 2020 to compute the entropy of a Gaussian Mixture Model.
I want to incorporate this into some deep learning I have in Jax, so I want the implementation to be JIT'able with Jax.
There is a working version attached below. The compilation times are horrendous though, and I think this has to do with the static variable for the number of partitions to iterate. If k and K are large, the number of partitions increase superexponentially. And it seems JAX decides to to some unrolling or something so the compilation time also increase superexponentially.
What can I do to make jax compile this faster (even if at the expense of slower runtime)?
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import functools


def gmm_max(logpi, mu, cov):
    """Return an upper bound the GMM density
    logpi: (K,)-array of the log-weights
    mu: (K, D)-array of the component means
    cov: (K,D,D)-array of the component covarainces

    if p(x) = sum_i pi_i N(x|mu_i, cov_i) then
    max(p(x)) <= sum_i pi_i max(N(x|mu_i, cov_i))
                = sum_i pi_i N(0|0, cov_i)
    """
    logpdfmaxs = jax.vmap(
        lambda m, c: jax.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(m, m, cov=c)
    )(mu, cov)
    res = jnp.sum(jnp.exp(logpdfmaxs + logpi))
    return res


@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=["K", "c"])
def partitions_(k, K, c):
    """
    PRECONDITION: c = combinations(k+K-1, k, exact=True)

    TODO come up with a way to NOT have to pass c, while still allowing JIT
    """

    def _inner(k, buffer, pos, carry):
        obuffer, opos = carry
        if pos == K - 1:
            updated_buffer = buffer.at[pos].set(k)
            return (obuffer.at[opos, :].set(updated_buffer), opos + 1)
        else:
            return jax.lax.fori_loop(
                0,
                k + 1,
                lambda i, carry: _inner(
                    k - i, buffer.at[pos].set(i), pos + 1, carry=carry
                ),
                carry,
            )

    buffer = jnp.zeros(K, dtype=jnp.int32)
    carry = (jnp.zeros((c, K), dtype=jnp.int32), 0)
    obuffer, opos = _inner(k=k, pos=0, buffer=buffer, carry=carry)
    return obuffer


def comb(n, k):
    """Compute n choose k via gamma function"""
    return jnp.exp(
        jax.scipy.special.gammaln(n + 1)
        - jax.scipy.special.gammaln(k + 1)
        - jax.scipy.special.gammaln(n - k + 1)
    )


def logfactorial(n):
    return jax.scipy.special.gammaln(n + 1)


def log_multinomial_coeff(ks):
    """Multinomial coefficient approximated with log-gamma-function"""
    return jax.scipy.special.gammaln(jnp.sum(ks) + 1) - jnp.sum(
        jax.scipy.special.gammaln(ks + 1)
    )


def expectation_of_powers(logpi, mu, cov, k, K, n_partitions):
    """Compute the closed form expectation of powers of a GMM.

    Equation 11 in the cited paper

    I would *really* like to not pass `K` and `n_partitions` as arguments, but I don't know how to do that with JIT

    PRECONDITION:
        sum(exp(logpi)) == 1
        n_partitions == int(round(comb(k+K-1, k))
    """
    assert logpi.ndim == 1
    assert len(mu) == len(cov) == K
    inv_covs = jax.vmap(jnp.linalg.inv)(cov)

    # Iterate over j1, ..., jK >= 0 where j1 + ... + jK = k
    result = 0.0
    partitions = partitions_(k, K, n_partitions)

    def _inner(j):
        def _inner2(ith_inv_cov, ith_mu, ith_cov, ith_logpi):
            cov_combined = jnp.linalg.inv(
                ith_inv_cov
                + jnp.sum(jax.vmap(lambda j_, ic: j_ * ic)(j, inv_covs), axis=0)
            )

            mu_combined = cov_combined @ (
                ith_inv_cov @ ith_mu
                + jnp.sum(
                    jax.vmap(lambda j_, ic, m_: j_ * ic @ m_)(j, inv_covs, mu), axis=0
                )
            )

            # Gaussian ratio
            log_N_ratio = jax.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(
                0, mean=ith_mu, cov=ith_cov
            ) - jax.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(
                0, mean=mu_combined, cov=cov_combined
            )

            # Product term
            log_product_term = jnp.sum(
                jax.vmap(
                    lambda j_, logpi_, mu_, cov_: (
                        j_
                        * (
                            logpi_
                            + jax.scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.logpdf(
                                0, mean=mu_, cov=cov_
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )(j, logpi, mu, cov),
                axis=0,
            )
            return ith_logpi + log_N_ratio + log_product_term

        log_inner_summands = jax.vmap(_inner2)(inv_covs, mu, cov, logpi)
        return jnp.exp(log_multinomial_coeff(j) + jax.nn.logsumexp(log_inner_summands))

    result = jnp.sum(jax.vmap(_inner)(partitions))
    return result


@functools.partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=["order", "K", "partition_sizes"])
def gmm_entropy_legendre_jax_(logpi, mu, cov, order, K, partition_sizes):
    """Entropy of a GMM using legendre polynomial approximation

    Formula due to Dahlke and Pacheko
    See equation 16 in the cited paper

    PRECONDITIONS:
        len(logpi) == K
        partition_sizes = [combinations(k+K-1, k, exact=True) for k in range(order+1)]
    """
    assert logpi.ndim == 1
    assert mu.ndim == 2
    d = mu.shape[1]
    assert mu.shape == (K, d), f"mu.shape={mu.shape}, K={K}, d={d}"
    assert cov.ndim == 3
    assert cov.shape == (K, d, d)
    N = order  # alias
    a = gmm_max(logpi, mu, cov) + 1e-3
    loga = jnp.log(a)

    # I cannot understand how to do this with vmap without making `combs` a non-concrete value
    Ep_px = [
        expectation_of_powers(logpi, mu, cov, k, K, combs)
        for k, combs in zip(range(0, N + 1), partition_sizes)
    ]

    def _summand_by_n(n):
        coeffs_sum = jnp.sum(
            jax.vmap(
                lambda j: (
                    +((-1) ** (n + j))
                    * ((j + 1) * loga - 1)
                    * jnp.exp(
                        logfactorial(n + j)
                        - logfactorial(n - j)
                        - 2 * logfactorial(j + 1)
                    )
                )
            )(jnp.arange(n + 1))
        )
        coeffs2_sum = jnp.sum(
            jax.vmap(
                lambda k, Ep_px_k: (
                    (-1) ** (n + k)
                    * jnp.exp(
                        logfactorial(n + k) - logfactorial(n - k) - 2 * logfactorial(k)
                    )
                    * Ep_px_k
                    / a**k
                )
            )(jnp.arange(n + 1), jnp.stack(Ep_px, axis=0)[: n + 1]),
        )

        return (2 * n + 1) * coeffs_sum * coeffs2_sum

    # I cannot understand how to do this with vmap without making `n` a non-concrete value
    result = 0.0
    for n in range(N + 1):
        result += _summand_by_n(n)

    return -result


def gmm_entropy_legendre_jax(logpi, mu, cov, order):
    """Entropy of a GMM using legendre polynomial approximation

    Formula due to Dahlke and Pacheko
    See equation 16 in the cited paper (or the corresponding formula in proof of theorem 4.5)
    """
    assert mu.ndim == 2
    K = mu.shape[0]
    D = mu.shape[1]
    assert logpi.shape == (K,), f"logpi.shape={logpi.shape}, K={K}"
    assert cov.shape == (K, D, D), f"cov.shape={cov.shape}, K={K}, D={D}"
    partition_sizes = tuple(int(round(comb(k + K - 1, k))) for k in range(order + 1))
    return gmm_entropy_legendre_jax_(
        logpi, mu, cov, order=order, K=K, partition_sizes=partition_sizes
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    order = 8

    def mvn_entropy_exact(cov):
        """The entropy of a single Gaussian with covariance matrix `cov`."""
        assert cov.ndim == 2
        k = cov.shape[0]
        assert cov.shape == (k, k)
        return (k / 2) * (1 + jnp.log(2 * jnp.pi)) + 0.5 * jnp.log(jnp.linalg.det(cov))

    logpi = jnp.array([0.0])
    mu = jnp.array([[10.0, -20]])
    cov = jnp.array([[[2, 0], [0, 7]]])
    a = mvn_entropy_exact(cov[0])
    print(a)
    a = gmm_entropy_legendre_jax(logpi, mu, cov, order=order)
    print(a)

    a = mvn_entropy_exact(jnp.array([[1.0]]))
    print(a)
    a = gmm_entropy_legendre_jax(
        jnp.array([0.0]), jnp.array([[0.0]]), jnp.array([[[1.0]]]), order=order
    )
    print(a)
    a = gmm_entropy_legendre_jax(
        jnp.log(jnp.ones(2) / 2),
        jnp.array([[0.0], [0.0]]),
        jnp.array([[[1.0]], [[1.0]]]),
        order=order,
    )
    print(a)


the slow compilation times are likely due to your use of for loops which you should replace with jax.lax.fori_loops

you're also using the builtin sum with generator expressions which should be replaced with vectorized operations with jax.numpy.sum

I did that now. The compilation time on one of my test cases went from 20 seconds to 3 seconds. Very nice! There is still one comprehension and on for-loop I cannot get rid of. Any advice would be welcome.

Since both remaining loops generate arrays with sizes given by the loop iteration, you've gone as far as you can without refactoring your code to use e.g. padded representations within the loops. Doing multiple passes via for loops with different shapes leads to long programs, and long programs will have long compile times.
